# flask login error aplicacion mensajes

Tags: python, flask

estoy aprendiendo programacion por mi cuenta (viendo videos y leyendo mucha documentacion) solo llevo dos meses y estaba intentando hacer una app e flask para enviar mensajes de un usuario a otro usando bases de datos, pero tengo dos fallos que no se arreglar, los mensajes se mandan duplicados, y ademas todos los ususarios tienen acceso a todos los mensajes (incluyendo los que no so para ellos). Os dejo el codigo del endpooint

```py
@app.route("/dashboard", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    users = db.query(User).all()
    form = Messageform()
    form.receiver_email.choices = get_choices(current_user)
    if request.method == "GET":
        messages = db.query(Mensaje).filter_by(receiver=current_user.email).all()
        return render_template("dashboard.html", messages=messages, form=form, current_user=current_user, users=users)

    else:
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            msg = Mensaje(subject=form.subject.data, message=form.message.data, receiver=form.receiver_email.data,
                          sender=current_user.email, read=False)
            db.add(msg)
            db.commit()
            data = "Your message has been sent"
            return render_template("dashboard.html", data=data, form=form, current_user=current_user, users=users,
                                   msg=msg)
```

Este es el html del template al que apunta el endpoint, intento hacer que los msgs solo aparezcan si el email de msg.recevier es el mismo del current user, pero asi no se ve ningun mensaje, ni los suyos ni los de los demas

```html
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}
Dashboard
{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('.static', filename='dashboard.css')}}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <h1 class="page-header">Welcome {{ current_user.name }}</h1>
          {% if messages %}
            <div class="row">
                <h3>New messages</h3><br>
<!--                {% if current_user.email == form.receiver_email %}-->
                        {% for msg in messages %}
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="card" id="{{ msg.id }}" style="width: 18rem;" onclick="window.location.href='/messages/{{ msg.id }}'">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Message from: {{ msg.sender }}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Subject: {{ msg.subject }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
<!--                {% endif %}-->
          {% endif %}

          </div><br>

          <div class="row ">
           <div class="col-12" >
               <h3>Send message</h3>
               <form method="post" action="/dashboard" class="form-group">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.subject) }}
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.message) }}
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.receiver_email) }}
                 <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" type="submit">Send</button>
                {% if data %}
                   <h5>{{ data }}</h5>
                {% endif %}
                </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: No tengo aún claro lo que pretendes, pero voy a hacer un disparo a ciegas. ¿No sería mejor filtrar la lista de mensajes a mostrar desde el código python y pasarle al template ya sólo los mensajes apropiados?

Comment: Hola buenas, has disparado bien a ciegas hehe, si eso es una magnifica idea si supiera como hacerlo... ten en cuenta que llevo dos meses aprendiendo por mi cuenta, sin haber programando nunca antes.

Comment: La idea es que cada vez que un usuario haga login, en su dashboard le salgan los mensajes que otros usuarios les han enviado, pero solo los que son para el, no todos los mensajes que hay enviados...., actualizao el codigo tal y como lo tengo ahora, aunque sigue sin funcionar

Comment: No estoy familiarizado con la forma en que lees los datos del formulario y esa clase `MessageForm` ¿estás usando `flask-wtf`? No lo he usado, por lo que no estoy seguro de si el problema estará ahí, pero yo intentaría imprimir el valor de las variables `current_user.email` y `form.receiver_email` para asegurarme de que tienen lo que esperas (el resultado de esos print se verían en la consola en la que Flask saca el log)

Comment: si estoy usando wt form, por que ya hice un ejercicio parecido sin wtform y queria probarlo,